# Vaadin couple of basic quesions to manipulate few widgets

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8

I am newbie about Vaadin. I am trying to manipulate following widgets.

```
private VerticalLayout layout;
ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar(0.0f);
Button downLoadButton;

private void setupLayout() {
    layout = new VerticalLayout();
    layout.setDefaultComponentAlignment(Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
    setContent(layout);
}

private void setStockDownloadUI() {
    TextField tf = new TextField("Downloading");
    tf.setValue("Downloading stock data. It takes about 15 seconds.");
    tf.setWidth("400");
    tf.setVisible(false);
    layout.addComponent(tf);
    bar.setHeight("100");
    bar.setWidth("500");
    bar.setIndeterminate(true);
    bar.setVisible(false);
    layout.addComponent(bar);
    Page.getCurrent().reload();
    downLoadButton = new Button("Start download", click -> {
        tf.setVisible(true);
        bar.setVisible(true);
        float current = bar.getValue();
        if (current < 1.0f)
            bar.setValue(current + 0.10f);
        stockService.downloadStockContent();
        startTimer();
        Notification.show("Downloading",
                "Stock data downloading. Please wait.",
                Notification.Type.TRAY_NOTIFICATION);
    });
    downLoadButton.addStyleName("huge");
    layout.addComponent(downLoadButton);
}


 void checkDownloadStatus() {
    stockElements = callBack.getDownloadedStock();
    if (stockElements != null && stockElements.size() != 0) {
        MessageBox
                .createInfo()
                .withCaption("Example 1")
                .withMessage("Hello World!")
                .withOkButton()
                    .open();
        bar.setVisible(false);

        layout.removeAllComponents();
        timer.shutdownNow();
        for (StockElement element : stockElements) {
            System.out.println(element.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

There are several issues. I am downloading some content from the web. First I set up the UI by setStockDownloadUI(). Where I set a progress bar. When downloading is done, I call checkDownloadStatus(). There I want to hide the progress bar. Also when the download button is clicked once, I want to disable it. So that it won't be clickable twice.

At checkDownloadStatus() I created a message box that never shows in the browser. Also, I called layout.removeAllComponents(); I try to remove everything when the download is done. But it has no effect.

Questions:

1. How to disable the button after it is clicked once?
2. How to remove progress bar or even all components from the VerticalLayout after the download is done?
3. How to show the message box?

**UPDATE**

I found that if I call method form another button click:

```
workaroundButton = new Button("Work around", click -> {
    this.bar.setVisible(false);
    this.layout.removeComponent(bar);
    this.layout.removeComponent(downLoadButton);
    this.layout.removeComponent(textField);
    layout.removeAllComponents();
});
```

Then it works. But it doesn't work if I just call those methods from my own callback method. But it is not acceptable. I believe I am missing something in my code.

**Update 2**

After the answer, I tried the following code. Even if I set a breakpoint by the debugger, it never hit the bp. So the code has never been executed. Am I missing something? I am trying to check the download status by the timer.

```
 @Push
 @Theme("mytheme")
 public class StockApplication extends UI {
   // code removed. 
 }


private void startTimer() {
    ScheduledExecutorService timer = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    timer.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            UI.getCurrent().access((() -> {
                // breakpoint never hit this book of code
                       MessageBox
                        .createInfo()
                        .withCaption("Wait")
                        .withMessage("Still downloading stock contents. Please check again  after a while")
                        .withOkButton(() -> System.out.println("Ok pressed."))
                        .open();
                checkDownloadStatus();}));

        }
    }, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

What is wrong? Please let me know how can I fix it?

I could fix it with the following code:-

```
private void startTimer() {
    UI ui = UI.getCurrent();
    timer.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            ui.access((() -> {
                checkDownloadStatus();}));
        }
    }, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

All credits go to one who gave me the hints by his/her valuable information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The first question is the easy one - `downLoadButton.setDisableOnClick(true)`

2+3. We're talking about [Vaadin Push](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/advanced/advanced-push.html) here.  As you've noticed, by default an update to a Vaadin component will only make it back to the browser if that change was triggered by the browser (e.g. clicking `workaroundButton` above).  To send an unsolicited update back to the browser you will need push enabled, which uses a Websocket behind the scenes to allow the browser to continue receiving updates.

The link above explains how to enable push for your UI.

Once push is enabled, it's very slick - you can manipulate widgets as normal and the changes still find their way back to the browser.  You just need to remember to wrap those updates in `UI.access()` to ensure you have the session lock.  E.g. :

```
ui.access(() -> checkDownloadStatus());
```

The `ui` is just your UI class, or you can get to it from any widget with `widget.getUI()`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried it. But something is strange. Please check my update2 section of the question

Comment: From reading through I would guess the `UI.getCurrent()` is returning null?  The `getCurrent()` comes from a ThreadLocal, but will only be set in a Vaadin callback, e.g. when clicking a button.  In a scheduled executor, it would not actually be available until you've made the `ui.access()` call.  Clearly the `ui` in Update2 is the `StockApplication`.  If `startTimer()` is in the same class `StockApplication.this.access( ... )` should do the trick, otherwise you would need to pass it through somehow.

Comment: No. I fixed the issue by  UI ui = UI.getCurrent(); Then I use the local variable ui.access((() -> {
                    checkDownloadStatus();})); This way it is working as expected. Thanks a lot.